# ConfigurationProperties not working with @Getter and @Setter

Tags: spring-boot, lombok, configurationproperties

I am trying to use `@ConfigurationProperties` with lombok `@Getter` and `@Setter`.

If I manually define the getters and setters everything works fine.  If I remove the actual getters and setters and add `@Getter` and `@Setter` spring cannot find any of the getters and setters.

Any ideas what I might be missing?

Comment: After doing a little more research, I think I need to install the lombok jar in eclipse/STS.  Thoughts? https://projectlombok.org/setup/eclipse

Comment: I'd say follow the website, and if it still doesn't work, raise an issue on their GitHub.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to resolve this issue by following the instructions at: https://projectlombok.org/setup/eclipse